# Gamma ray energies from an electron annihilation?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, collision

I recently started studying Special Relativity for fun through reading the classic book Spacetime Physics. I came across a practice problem that I have difficult understanding:

> An electron moving with some kinetic energy K collides with another electron to produce 2 gamma rays travelling at different angles with respect to the moving electron. Determine an expression for the energies as a function of the electron mass, energy, and angle of outgoing rays.

I'm not quite sure how to set up the conservation momentum equations to solve for this...?

Comment: actually you likely need conservation of the net momentum 4-vector.  Presumably the second electron is at rest?

Comment: Yes the second electron is at rest

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the mathematics involved with 4-momentum, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: see here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum or here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: is it possible you are misquoting and it is an electron hitting a positron? Seems to me an undefined problem .

Comment: electrons annihilate only on positrons. The incoming could be a positron and the one at rest an electron

Comment: Yes, I misread the problem. It's an electron and positron

Comment: See http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity/seven.pdf, Sec.7.5, pgs.146-150, really good intro to relativistic collisions.